# Select all element with a not null id, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to implement .draggable class to all elements in my document, with an existing id using jQuery 1.4.2

```
<div id="blabla">asdsda</div> -> OK
<div>dsds</div> -> NOT OK
```

Is this possible ?

i tried : `$("*[id!=null]")` but i does not work :s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selectors on custom data attribute that are not empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177815/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attribute-that-are-not-empty)

Comment: To select with js selecter, do `document.querySelectorAll('[id]')`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$("*[id]")
```

should work, and - for the record -

```
$("*:not([id])")
```

is the opposite.

Comment: +1 But I think I'd probably limit the query to descendants of `body` just to make it a little quicker. `$('body [id]')`

Comment: Marginally, yes. If at all? Well, if there's one additional tag, (HTML for example) then of course there must be *some* difference, though marginal. Also, what if a tag in the HEAD has an ID? Maybe calling `.draggable()` on a `<script>` tag is innocuous... but then maybe not.

Comment: @patrick: From a "time to execute" perspective, I do not expect any difference that's more than academic. From a "be specific to avoid bugs" perspective, your's may be the better choice, however.

Comment: Fair enough. :o) I certainly don't disagree with your assessment of the performance difference. Such is the case of many performance-related 'best practices' we may do.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('[id]')
```

This will grab all elements that have an 'id' attribute.

Or to get all divs with an 'id' attribute you can do:

```
$('div[id]')
```

[Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
$("div[id]")
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWdDQ/).