# jQuery selectors on custom data attribute that are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a simple custom tooltip plugin for jQuery that for every element that has a `data-custom-tooltipset`. So, something like :

```
<a href= . . . " data-custom-tooltip="This is my tooltip Text">Hhahaha</a>
```

OR

```
<button data-custom-tooltip="This is my tooltip for the button Tex">Haha Button :) </button >
```

So, the function to display the tooltip would be triggered only if the `data-custom-tooltip`  is **NOT** empty.

Close enough to this : [jQuery selectors on custom data attributes using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5)

Comment: Try this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5

Comment: The question is: what is  the function to display the tooltip so it would be triggered only if the data-custom-tooltip is NOT empty ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and remove the empty ones

```
$('[data-custom-tooltip]:not([data-custom-tooltip=""])')
```

or

```
$('[data-custom-tooltip]').not('[data-custom-tooltip=""]')
```

---

or based on what [@VisioN said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177815/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attribute-that-are-not-empty/22177963?noredirect=1#comment33661809_22177963) with the [Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```
var xxx = $('[data-custom-tooltip][data-custom-tooltip!=""]');
```

Comment: `$('[data-custom-tooltip!=""]')` seems more logical...?

Comment: @VisioN it will also select the element without data-custom-tooltip attribute.

Comment: @VisioN yes, with a little modification.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
$("[data-custom-tooltip]:not([data-custom-tooltip='']").click(function(){alert("clicked");});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/12/)

Comment: For some reason using it with `live()` doesn't seem to work, but with `on()`  it does.

Comment: live has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed in 1.9! What old version of jQuery are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var tooltip_el = $('[data-custom-tooltip]').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).data('custom-tooltip')) != '';
});
```